# Freeing memory in a custom stack allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

In my custom stack allocator, I allocate a large amount of memory at when the program launches using `malloc()`, then at program shutdown I `free()` all the memory allocated.

So basically it looks like this:

```
//start up
m_pInitialPosition = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

//shutdown
free(m_pInitilaPosition);
```

When I need to create a new object I call `allocateNew()`:

```
 Actor* pActor = getStackAllocator().allocateNew<Actor>();
 *pActor = Actor();
```

This is what `allocateNew()` looks like:

```
template <class T>
T* allocateNew()
{
   //allocate returns void*
   return new (allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T;
}
```

The problem occurs (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse exception) if I call:

```
delete pActor;
```

If I simply remove that line the problem disappears and there are no memory leaks because the I still call `free()` in the stack allocator, but the destructor of Actor is not called...

So what can I change to ensure that the destructor is called?

Comment: What does the deallocation complement of `allocateNew` look like? That would be where you need to call the destructor.

Comment: Where does the memory from the first `malloc` call get used? It seems that you are just allocating new memory for the `pActor`. Where does the `malloc`ed memory get used? And why are you using `malloc` in the first place? You should be using `new` and `delete`. `malloc` isen't aware of objects or destructors.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh the allocate() method returns a pointer to the memory allocated using the malloc(), so the new() inside the allocateNew() method doesn't really allocate new memory.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`? What's wrong with `new`? Why are you using `delete` with `malloc`? This is wrong.

Comment: @EitanT: He is using `free` with `malloc`, the mistake is using `delete` to pair with _placement_ `new`.

Comment: @EitanT I use `malloc/free` to allocate say 100mb. Then I call `new (pointer) T()` which is a `placement new` to create new objects where "pointer" is a pointer to a memory location inside those 100mb allocated using malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `delete`, the object pointed by `pActor` will be destructed and the memory will be freed using the default deallocator (could be free()), not yours. Since the object has been allocated by your allocator, it cannot work.

Define a new method to handle object deletion like this one :

```
template<class T> void deleteObject(T *obj) {
   if (obj!=nullptr) {  // do nothing is obj is null
      obj->~T(); // call the object's destructor
      deallocate(obj);  // your method to handle deallocation in your 'memory pool'
   }
}
```

And replace your delete by :

```
 getStackAllocator().deleteObject(pActor);
```

This article explains how to make a custom memory allocator : http://bitsquid.blogspot.fr/2010/09/custom-memory-allocation-in-c.html

---

Moreover, I have a doubt about your code. What are these lines supposed to do ?

```
Actor* pActor = getStackAllocator().allocateNew<Actor>();
*pActor = Actor();
```

1- If allocateNew() performs both allocation & default construction, it is ok but the second line is useless ?
2- If allocateNew() only performs allocation without initializing the object, the second line is wrong : it calls the assignment operator on an uninitialized object.

Answer (score 2):

`delete pActor` is not the appropriate complement to placement `new`. To "undo" the object construction `new (allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T` you need to call the destructor only, not use `delete` which will also try to deallocate memory at the location pointer to by `pActor`

E.g.

```
pActor->~Actor();
```

You should probably wrap this up in a member function of your stack allocator class so that it's clients don't have to magically know how to deallocate objects that you give them and to give you the freedom to update your allocator's implementation.

E.g.

```
template <class T>
void deallocate(T* t)
{
    t->~T();
}
```